# How to redirect sqlite3 output to a file

Tags: io-redirection, sqlite

I installed `sqlite3` and want to use it to recover information from `stylish.sqlite`  which is located in my Firefox profile folder and is generated by the [Stylish extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/):

```
$ cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/w4wcp85s.default
$ sqlite3 stylish.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
style_meta  styles
sqlite> SELECT * FROM styles;
6||||YouTube|/* AGENT_SHEET */ 
/* ▓▓ NIGHTSHIFT - eye care:                                 ▓▓
   ▓▓_http://userstyles.org/styles/18192/nightshift-eye-care_▓▓ */

@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document regexp("https?://www.youtube.com/.*")  {
body,html {min-height: 100%!important; }
html, body{background-color:#111!important}
body>*:not(:empty){background-color:#222!important}
body>*>*:not(:empty){background-color:#222!important}
body>*>*>*:not(:empty){background-color:#282828!important}
...
```

My question is this: how can I capture the output of `sqlite> SELECT * FROM styles;` to a file? (I know I can select the output in the terminal and copy it to a file.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run it all as a single command:

```
$ sqlite3 stylish.sqlite "SELECT * FROM styles;" > somefile.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ sqlite3 addons.sqlite "select * from icon;" > somefile.txt

$ cat somefile.txt 
1|32|https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/354/354399-32.png?modified=1369154804
1|64|https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/354/354399-64.png?modified=1369154804
```

#### Using tee

If you want to see the output as it's being written to the file you can use `tee` instead.

```
$ sqlite3 addons.sqlite "select * from icon;" | tee somefile.txt
1|32|https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/354/354399-32.png?modified=1369154804
1|64|https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/354/354399-64.png?modified=1369154804
```

Comment: Won't work with binary blobs.

Answer (score 2):

### From inside the SQLite command line interface

If you are working inside the command line interface of SQLite, you cannot use redirections or pipes.
However, you can use the command `.output` (the command `.mode` could be useful too).

```sql
.output some_file
SELECT * FROM table; /* SQLite saves the output in 'some_file' */

.output
SELECT * FROM table; /* SQLite presents the output again in the screen */
```

Two notes:

- As soon you run `.output some_file`, the output file is opened in mode "w",
  thus be careful if the file already exists and contains some data.
- To unset the redirection you must use the `.output` command without arguments.

### An extra

You can produce a CSV file using the command `.mode`.

```sql
.mode csv
.output some_file
SELECT * FROM table;
.output
.mode
```